# Sprite Kit only allow one touch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have looked for a similar question and didn't find one, so I apologize if this has already been asked, but I am having issues with limiting the amount of touches that SKScene will allow me to have. I have implemented the touchesBegan:withEvent: method, and have set up my SKAction(s) for the animation, but what I am wanting is while the sprite node is animating, I don't want it to have the ability of accepting another touch.

I tried to count the amount of touches that is happening, but that didn't work in any way, so I am at a stopping point.

So, my basic question is: How do I create a "one touch, then wait for animation to end before another touch can happen" in my scene?

Here is the code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

SKAction *jump = [SKAction moveToY:400 duration:.4];
SKAction *down = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) duration:.4];
SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[jump, down]];

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    NSInteger touchesMax = 1;
    NSInteger actualTouches = [touches count];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)actualTouches);

    actualTouches++;

    if (actualTouches > touchesMax) {
        [farmer removeAllActions];
    }
    else {
        [farmer runAction:action];
    }
}
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You can try with creating variable "actualTouches" as global for this method. As there may be due to actualTouches variable is re initialising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would work.  At the start of `touchesBegan` do

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Then define a new `SKAction` to enable user interaction:

```
SKAction *enable = [SKAction runBlock:^{ self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; }];
```

Add that to your sequence:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[jump, down, enable]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was useful to me. However, be cognizant that running `removeAllActions` will prevent touch from being reenabled.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for your case:

> How do I create a "one touch, then wait for animation to end before another touch can happen" in my scene?

Is to disable the touch upon starting the animation using         `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`

And reenabling it once animation is done.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    SKAction *jump = [SKAction moveToY:400 duration:.4];
    SKAction *down = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) duration:.4];
    SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[jump, down]];

    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [farmer runAction:action completion^{
          [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }];
}
```

Now if you still want to have touch functionality, just not perform action you could do this.
Add property to your scene, lets call it animating.

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)BOOL animating;
```

Then change your code to take this value into account:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    SKAction *jump = [SKAction moveToY:400 duration:.4];
    SKAction *down = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) duration:.4];
    SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[jump, down]];

    self.animating = YES;
    [farmer runAction:action completion^{
        self.animating = NO;
    }];

}
```

This way animating flag will be YES while action is running, upon completion it will be set to NO, and new action can be run.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check it that way. You can use runAcrion:forKey on SKSpriteNode and after that you can see if the action is running:

```
if (![farmer actionForKey:@"ActionKey"])
    [farmer runAction: runAction:action withKey:@"ActionKey"]
```

Now you just run action if the sprite in not running it.

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

It is implemented there - once sprite been touched and move, touch again and nothing happen.